# Weights, Bias and cost are returning NaN for all epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

My outputted weights, cost and bias for my multivariable prediction model are always NaN no matter what. The model has no exit code, so this is a logical error.

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Real+estate+valuation+data+set
heres the dataset I used

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

#params
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000

#not really that important. I use it so I can see what happens every 100 epochs
steps = 100
#generating random numbers from 0 to 20
```

Imports and initialization of variables

```
#training sets, a bunch of random arrays with random values
cols = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Age = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[0])
Age = Age.iloc[:,2]

MRT = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[1])
MRT = MRT.iloc[:,3]

Conv = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[2])
Conv = Conv.iloc[:,4]
Conv = Conv.astype(float)

latitude = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[3])
latitude = latitude.iloc[:,5]

longitude = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[4])
longitude = longitude.iloc[:,6]

Price = pd.read_excel('Real estate valuation data set.xlsx', sheet_names='Sheet', usecols=cols[5])
Price = Price.iloc[:,7]


age = []
mrt = []
conv = []
lat = []
long = []
price = []
for i in range(50):
    age.append(Age[i])
    mrt.append(MRT[i])
    conv.append(Conv[i])
    lat.append(latitude[i])
    long.append(longitude[i])
    price.append(Price[i])

a = np.array(age)
m = np.array(mrt)
co = np.array(conv)
lo = np.array(lat)
la = np.array(long)
p = np.array(price)
```

The 6 np arrays above are 50 unit 1-D arrays with floats in them.
The p array will be my dependent variable unit and the rest are independent.

```
#I made the arrays have 50 samples each
n_samples = 50

A = tf.placeholder("float")
B = tf.placeholder("float")
C = tf.placeholder("float")
D = tf.placeholder("float")
E = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

random = random.uniform(0,20)
#weights and biases
W1 = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight1")
W2 = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight2")
W3 = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight3")
W4 = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight4")
W5 = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight5")
bias = tf.Variable((random), name = "Bias")
```

My placeholder variables. A, B, C, D, E are my independent variables. Y is my dependent. The rest are my weights and biases

```
#linear model multiply x by weights and biases to get a y
pred = tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(tf.multiply(A, W1), tf.multiply(B, W2)), tf.add(tf.multiply(C, W3), tf.multiply(D, W4))), tf.multiply(E, W5)), bias)

#cost function to reduce the error. MSE
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

#minimize cost taking steps of 0.01 down the parabola
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

#initialize all variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

my prediction, cost and optimizer functions.

```
#start running the neural network
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #zip the training values together into tuples

        for (un, deux, tres, quart, cinq, six) in zip(a, m, co, lo, la, p):

            #feed the optimizer the training values
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={A: un, B: deux, C: tres, D: quart, E: cinq, Y: six})
```

I zip all my training variables together into a tuple with 6 units and run it through my optimizer. a, m, co, lo, la and p are my datasets with floats in them and A, B, C, D, E, Y are my placeholders that will run in `pred = tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(tf.add(tf.multiply(A, W1), tf.multiply(B, W2)), tf.add(tf.multiply(C, W3), tf.multiply(D, W4))), tf.multiply(E, W5)), bias)`

```
        if (epoch+1) % steps == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={A: a, B: m, C: co, D: lo, E: la, Y: p})
            print("Epoch:" + str((epoch+1)), "cost=" + str(c),  "W1=" + str(sess.run(W1)), "W2=" + str(sess.run(W2)), "W3=" + str(sess.run(W3)), "W4=" + str(sess.run(W4)), "W5=" + str(sess.run(W5)), "bias=" + str(sess.run(bias)))
```

This print returns NaN for all my epochs

Comment: Don't you need to specify the shapes for the placeholders?

Comment: @amityadav In all the regressions I've implemented, I've never specified the shape and they still worked. Does specifying the shape have a purpose or is it just for readability.

Comment: oh, you're right. it's only a sanity check